# Django cookies and headers

Tags: python, django, cookies

In Django (and in general), is a cookie also a header, just like, e.g. `User-Agent`?
That is, are these two methods equivalent in Django?

**Using `set_cookie`:**

```
response.set_cookie('food', 'bread')
response.set_cookie('drink', 'water')
```

**Using header setting:**

```
response['Cookie'] = ('food=bread; drink=water')
# I'm not sure whether 'Cookie' should be capitalized or not
```

Also, if we can set a cookie using the second way, how can we include additional info,
like `path`, `max_age`, etc. in the string? Shall we just separate them with some special
character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'd be much easier if you use `set_cookie`. But yes, you can set the cookie by
setting the response header:

```
response['Set-Cookie'] = ('food=bread; drink=water; Path=/; max_age=10')
```

However, since resetting `Set-Cookie` in `response` object will clear out the previous
one, you cannot have more than one `Set-Cookie` header in Django. Let's see
why.

Observe in [response.py, `set_cookie` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L146):

```
class HttpResponseBase:

    def __init__(self, content_type=None, status=None, mimetype=None):
        # _headers is a mapping of the lower-case name to the original case of
        # the header (required for working with legacy systems) and the header
        # value. Both the name of the header and its value are ASCII strings.
        self._headers = {}
        self._charset = settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
        self._closable_objects = []
        # This parameter is set by the handler. It's necessary to preserve the
        # historical behavior of request_finished.
        self._handler_class = None
        if mimetype:
            warnings.warn("Using mimetype keyword argument is deprecated, use"
                          " content_type instead",
                          DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
            content_type = mimetype
        if not content_type:
            content_type = "%s; charset=%s" % (settings.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE,
                    self._charset)
        self.cookies = SimpleCookie()
        if status:
            self.status_code = status

        self['Content-Type'] = content_type

    ...

    def set_cookie(self, key, value='', max_age=None, expires=None, path='/',
                   domain=None, secure=False, httponly=False):
        """
        Sets a cookie.

        ``expires`` can be:
        - a string in the correct format,
        - a naive ``datetime.datetime`` object in UTC,
        - an aware ``datetime.datetime`` object in any time zone.
        If it is a ``datetime.datetime`` object then ``max_age`` will be calculated.

        """
        self.cookies[key] = value
        if expires is not None:
            if isinstance(expires, datetime.datetime):
                if timezone.is_aware(expires):
                    expires = timezone.make_naive(expires, timezone.utc)
                delta = expires - expires.utcnow()
                # Add one second so the date matches exactly (a fraction of
                # time gets lost between converting to a timedelta and
                # then the date string).
                delta = delta + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
                # Just set max_age - the max_age logic will set expires.
                expires = None
                max_age = max(0, delta.days * 86400 + delta.seconds)
            else:
                self.cookies[key]['expires'] = expires
        if max_age is not None:
            self.cookies[key]['max-age'] = max_age
            # IE requires expires, so set it if hasn't been already.
            if not expires:
                self.cookies[key]['expires'] = cookie_date(time.time() +
                                                           max_age)
        if path is not None:
            self.cookies[key]['path'] = path
        if domain is not None:
            self.cookies[key]['domain'] = domain
        if secure:
            self.cookies[key]['secure'] = True
        if httponly:
            self.cookies[key]['httponly'] = True
```

Two things worth noticing here:

1. `set_cookie` method will take care of handling `datetime` in `expires` 
   for you, and you will have to set it yourself if you set it yourself.
2. `self.cookie` is a dictionary of dictionaies. So each `key` will add a `["Set-Cookie"]` in the header, as you will see shortly.

The `cookies` object inside `HttpResponse` will then get passed to
[`WSGIHandler`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L224), and get appended to the response header:

```
response_headers = [(str(k), str(v)) for k, v in response.items()]
for c in response.cookies.values():
    response_headers.append((str('Set-Cookie'), str(c.output(header=''))))
```

The code above is also why only `set_cookie()` allow multiple `Set-Cookie` in the response header, and that setting cookie directly to the `Response` object will only return one `Set-Cookie`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but change “Cookie” to “Set-Cookie” and add “Path=/” to make it site wide.

```
response["Set-Cookie"] = "food=bread; drink=water; Path=/"
```

**Edit:**

After trying this out myself I found an interesting quirk, `set_cookie` doesn't group together similar cookies (same path, expires, domain etc.) in the same header. It just adds another “Set-Cookie” into the response. Understandable, as checking and messing with strings would probably take more time than having a few extra bytes in the HTTP headers (and would be a micro optimisation at best).

```
response.set_cookie("food",  "kabanosy")
response.set_cookie("drink", "ardbeg")
response.set_cookie("state", "awesome")

# result in these headers
#   Set-Cookie: food=kabonosy; Path=/
#   Set-Cookie: drink=ardbeg; Path=/
#   Set-Cookie: state=awesome; Path=/

# not this
#   Set-Cookie:food=kabanosy; drink=ardbeg; state=awesome; Path=/
```

Comment: So, what if I am to set two different cookies, with different `path` and `max_age` parameters; but using the `response["Set-Cookie"]=...` syntax?

Comment: To be honest, you're better off using `set_cookie` as there is no real benefit to be had from setting the headers yourself. It would be something like this though: `response["Set-Cookie"] = "food=kabanosy; Max-Age=86400; Path=/"`.

Comment: I know it is basically more convenient to use `set_cookie`, but I would like to understand its relation with the `HttpResponse` object and with headers.

Comment: Anyway, I wrote an answer on the post with some explanation on the behavior you explored, about `set_cookie` setting multiple `Set-Cookie`s in the response.

Answer (score 1):

A snippet from the code of **`HttpResponse`** class:

```
class HttpResponse(object):

    #...

    def __init__(self, content='', mimetype=None, status=None,

        #...

        self.cookies = SimpleCookie()

    #...

    def set_cookie(self, key, value='', max_age=None, expires=None, path='/',
                   domain=None, secure=False, httponly=False):

        self.cookies[key] = value

        #...
```

That is, whenever `response.set_cookie()` is called, it either places a new cookie
`value` at `response.cookies[key]` or changes the existing value if there is one at that key.
It explains why it sets multiple `Set-Cookie` headers.
I wonder how we could do the same thing with `response['Set-Cookie']`.